# Tkinter Menu Display

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I am new to using Tkinter and I am trying to create menus and it does not display even though I think I followed it through.
I really do not know what is missing.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.wm_title("Tkiner GUI Test")

def hello():
    print("Hello World!")

menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=hello)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=hello)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)


editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=hello)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=hello)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=hello)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=hello)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, I only see an empty window with no menus.
[image: Result of Window]

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. It works for me on Linux and Windows using Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, the menubar appears like it does for all other applications in OSX -- along the top of the display. It will *not* appear at the top of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the breakthrough. I cant believe i missed that :)